Can you conclude $f(x)=F'(x)$ from $\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm dx = F(b)-F(a)$?
Based on the fundamental theorem of calculus can you conclude $f(x)=F'(x)$ from $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) \mathrm dx = F(b)-F(a)$? I would imagine that if it's true for all $a$ and $b$ on the domain of $f$ that would need to be true, but what if $a$ and $b$ are limited to a subdomain of $f$?

What are you assuming about $f$? Continuity?

I assume that $f$ is continuous on some interval $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and $F$ is defined on the same interval.

If there is some fixed $a \in I$ such that for all $b \in I$, $\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a)$, then $F$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ and $F' = f$ on $I$.

If there is some fixed $b \in I$ such that for all $a \in I$, $\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a)$, then $F$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ and $F' = f$ on $I$.

If both $f$ and $F$ are analytic on $I$ and there is a $a$ such that for all $b$ in a non-empty open sub-interval $J$ of $I$, $\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a)$, then $F' = f$ on $I$.


The first two points are exactly the fundamental theorem of calculus. the third one is the fundamental theorem of calculus and the uniqueness of analytic continuation (if you don't know what "analytic" means, please ignore this point). If the equality
$$
\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a),
$$
only holds for some $(a,b) \in S \subset I^2$, set $G$ to be the primitive of $f$ which verifies $G(a_0) = F(a_0)$ for some arbitrary point $a_0 \in I$. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, for all $(a,b) \in S$,
$$
G(b) - G(a) = F(b) - F(a).
$$
From here, when $(a,b) \in I^2$, write that $a \sim b$ if there is a finite sequence $a = t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_{k - 1},t_k = b$ of elements of $I$ such that for all $i$, $(t_{i - 1},t_i) \in S$ or $(t_i,t_{i - 1}) \in S$ or $t_{i - 1} = t_i$. We easily see that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.
Claim : If for all $(a,b) \in I^2$, $a \sim b$, then $F = G$. Reciprocally, if there are $(a,b) \in I^2$ such that $a \not\sim b$, there exists $f$ and $F$ such that $F \neq G$.
For the first point, let $b$ be an arbitrary point of $I$. By assumption, $a_0 \sim b$ thus we may find a sequence $a_0 = t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_k = b$ such that for all $i$, $(t_{i - 1},t_i) \in S$ or $(t_i,t_{i - 1}) \in S$ or $t_{i - 1} = t_i$. Therefore, for all $i$,
$$
G(t_i) - G(t_{i - 1}) = F(t_i) - F(t_{i - 1}).
$$
By definition, $G(a_0) = F(a_0)$ so by induction, for all $i$, $G(t_i) = F(t_i)$. In particular, $G(b) = F(b)$. It is true for all $b$ so $F = G$ hence $F$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ and $F' = f$.
For the reciprocal, if all pairs of elements in $I$ are not equivalent for $\sim$, choose $f = 0$ and,
$$
F(b) = 0 \textrm{ if } b \sim a_0, \qquad F(b) = 1 \textrm{ else}.
$$
By assumption, $F$ is not identically $0$. $F(a_0) = 0$ because $a_0 \sim a_0$ so $G = 0$. We deduce that $F \neq G$. Notice that $F$ is not even continuous so it doesn't make any sens to write $F'$. We now have to verify that for all $(a,b) \in S$, $G(b) - G(a) = F(b) - F(a)$ to conclude the proof.
Indeed, if $(a,b) \in S$, $a \sim b$ so $F(b) - F(a) = 0 = G(b) - G(a)$ ($F(a) = F(b)$ and they equal $0$ or $1$ in function of the equivalence classe of $a$ and $b$).

Let $$G(x)=\int\limits_a^xf(t)\,dt$$  Then $$G(b)-G(a)=\int\limits_a^bf(t)\,dt$$ Moreover it can be checked easily that  $G'(x)=f(x)$ for $a<x<b,$ $G'_+(a)=f(a)$ and $G'_-(b)=f(b).$ Thus $[G(x)-F(x)]'=0,$ i.e. $G(x)-F(x)$ is a constant function. Hence $$G(b)-F(b)=G(a)-F(a)$$ which gives $$F(b)-F(a)=G(b)-G(a) $$
